# This email address is not available. Choose a different address

Tags: icloud, apple-id

I just reset my password and now trying to sign in w/ my email address, however can't pass "verification of your email address" step:

After entering verification code (got it through email), I get following message:

> This email address is not available. Choose a different address.

Please advise.

Comment: I'm *NOT* trying to change my Apple ID, yet just to sign in...

Comment: Did you fail to login many times before you reset your password? You may wish to call Apple Support the account might be locked / disabled and they will have to unlock it.

Comment: Ok, will call Apple

Answer (score 2):

This indicates that another AppleID has reserved your chosen email address as a secondary security, [rescue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/370979/5472), email alias or primary email for AppleID.

You have a couple options to fix this:

1. Go to each of your Apple ID you control and ensure no use of this email.
2. Contact Apple Support. They will generally never divulge the other account since they can’t tell you from someone trying to hack into your account so they may be able to help or they may tell you to [choose another email](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180280/how-do-i-switch-my-apple-id-email-to-a-previously-used-rescue-email) or repeat step 1.